# Can someone help correct my text in chinese

Tags: writing, writing-critique

I need to write a short text in chinese but I'm not sure if it is well written or if there are some awkward parts. Can anyone help me?

在我的心里，中国不仅仅是一个遥远的国度；它是自我童年以来一直伴随着我的醒梦。我对中国文化的第一次接触可以追溯到我与祖父一起观看经典功夫电影的下午，我被演员的高难度动作和古老中国的壮丽景观所惊艳。从那时起，我对这个国家的崇敬之情便日益增长。每天晚上，我都会沉浸在一部中国小说的篇章中，被带入一个神奇的世界，在那里，龙与英雄在史诗般的战斗中交错。

我的梦想中充满了这种迷恋：学习汉语，品尝一碗地道的北京炸酱面，在繁华的胡同里沉醉；或者在一座神圣的山巅上静坐冥想。尽管我尚未踏上中国的土地，但我的思想经常漫游于上海老城区的曲折小巷或喜马拉雅山的雪峰之间。

中国也是一种对探索和发现的持续呼唤。每一本书籍，每一部电影，每一次与中国朋友的交谈都拓展了我的视野，激发了我对这个拥有悠久文化的国家的热情。也许有一天，我会有幸亲眼目睹长城的壮丽、观赏兵马俑的庄严，或者只是在北京的胡同里闲逛。在那之前，我的心将永远充满对这个国家的热爱和渴望，这个国家自童年时期就已经俘获了我的想象力。

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you write this or copy it from some internet site?  It is like seeing someone madly adore a caged animal and desperately wanting to pet and hug it while ignoring the dark fact that the animal is not free. Just my personal feeling

Comment: Anyone who could write this without any help do not need much help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me share with you my experience:

中国不仅仅是一个遥远的国度；它是自我童年以来一直伴随着我的醒梦。

中国不仅仅是一个遥远的国度；也是从小一直伴随着我的一场梦境。(醒梦 is not a usual word in Chinese)

我与祖父一起观看经典功夫电影的下午

我与祖父一起观看一部经典功夫电影的那天下午(This is an Anglicized structure)

龙与英雄在史诗般的战斗中交错。

猛龙与英雄在史诗般的战斗场景中交替出现。(Two-word phrase is more common)

学习汉语，品尝一碗地道的北京炸酱面，在繁华的胡同里沉醉；

学习汉语，品尝一碗地道的北京炸酱面，沉醉在繁华的胡同里；(The same V+object or + adverbial of place

在那之前，我的心将永远充满对这个国家的热爱和渴望，这个国家自童年时期就已经俘获了我的想象力。This sentence seems to have been changed from the following structure: Until then, my heart will always be filled with love and longing for this country, which has captured my imagination since childhood.

我的心将永远充满对这个自我童年时期就深得我心的国家的热爱和渴望(Attributives in Chinese, no matter how long they are, are placed before the noun they modify）

Answer (score 0):

作为母语者，对我而言除去下面几个词稍显生硬外，其他部分写得很棒。
“醒梦”-这个词几乎无人使用，可改为“梦境”（它是自我童年以来一直伴随着我的醒梦）、“交错”-交错一词似乎不用来形容活物，可改为“缠斗”（龙与英雄在史诗般的战斗中交错）“迷恋”-感觉改为“向往”更加合适一些（我的梦想中充满了这种迷恋）